# File Download with SAP .NET Connector

Tags: .net, sap-erp, sap-dotnet-connector

I am currently working with a SAP .NET Connector. I know, the new standard is webservices but the company I am working for does not provide these for now.

Connecting to the system and getting structure data is no problem at all. I just cannot find out how to checkout/download a file through the .NET Connector.

According to the companies specifications I have to use the BAPI `BAPI_DOCUMENT_CHECKOUTVIEW2` to get the files but no clue how to download them.

Does anybody have a bit of experience with downloading files from SAP ERP? A small example would be very nice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BAPI the company mentions is just another function module (like your getting structure data).

You cannot directly retrieve files from SAP. The company may have the ability to save a file onto a shared location so you can retrieve the files from this location with .NET.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will check this and try to find a solution.